# Finding Ve for a 3 input AND gate TTL circuit for different logic combinations

Tags: transistors, simulation, falstad

I'm designing a circuit that takes 3 24V input signals and pulls a 50 ohm resistor to ground when all three signals are high. My main concern is the voltages across different pins of the transistors for different logic combinations.

The circuit is designed such that when HIGH input received on all 3 transistors, the transistors act as a closed switch, pulling the 50 ohm resistor to ground. The Calculations I have done for this circuit tells me it should work as intended.

My concern is that when the first transistor is in cut-off mode (acting as an open switch), anything but a HIGH HIGH signal on the other two bases causes Voltage from the base to the emitter of first transistor to be high in magnitude and negative on circuit sims. I'm unsure how to calculate this value.

Additionally, when all signals are LOW, how is Ve calculated for the first two transistors. From my understanding, the circuit is open therefore there should be no connection from collector to emitter, however the emitter voltage seems to depend on the collector voltage.

I apologise if there is something obvious I'm missing.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome ... are you making a 3-input AND gate?  With 24V inputs?  Can I ask what it's for?

Comment: @jonathanjo Hi, the AND gate is to pull one side of an automotive relay (modelled as 50Ohm resistor for steady state) to ground. I originally designed this with 5V input signals and while I didn't quite understand it, the voltage shown in the images was within the tollerance for the transistors I am looking to use, so I concluded there would be no issue. I've been asked to look into modifying the circuit to work with 24V inputs as these are the current outputs of the already established circuits.

Comment: With 24 V input signals I expect 24 V load/relay. Try find a way that all ("input") transistors (BJT: current controlled current) are controlled in reference to a common potential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this stacked arrangement of bipolar transistors is often taught to be an implementation of AND, it's fraught with problems, not the least of which is reverse-biased base-emitter junctions.

Base-emitter junctions behave like zener diodes, with reverse breakdown voltages as low as 5V. That junction begins to conduct when the base tries to drop lower than 5V below the emitter, and clamps the difference at 5V. In your circuit, if you raise the second input potential, the result is a current path shown in red here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fesRqL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That may or may not be problematic, but it's certainly not desired behaviour.

Another issue you face is what happens when you take inputs above 12V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPbcLi.png)</sup>

The base-collector junction is just another diode, conducting freely when that junction is forward biased. Here you see significant current flowing the wrong way through the load, which may not be enough to activate a relay, but it's not ideal.

Another problem is the stacking of collector-emitter voltage drops when they are all on. \$V_{CE}\$ can be many tenths of a volt (depending on the transistor model), when passing a lot of collector current. They all add up, reducing the voltage available for the load:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuYU4P.png)</sup>

All these problems are easy to resolve. Here we use diodes D1, D2 and D3, and resistor R1, in a "Diode-AND" arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0OLF7.png)</sup>

Node X is held high by R1, unless any of the inputs A, B or C are brought low. Then one or more of the diodes become forward biased, pulling X low. The forward voltage of those diodes prevent X from falling below the transistor's own base threshold, so we use D4 and D5 to raise the voltage required at X to switch on the transistor.

In your circuit, and mine above, we rely on the the gain of a single transistor to drive the load, but even with a gain of 100 or so, it requires significant current (tens of milliamps) from the inputs. Your 1kΩ input resistors dissipate more than 500mW, and would have to be quite beefy. These inconveniences can be mitigated with an additional transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC1Xbx.png)</sup>

R1 has increased ten-fold, requiring input sources to sink only a milliamp or two. Q1 will sink about 10mA from Q2's base, and Q2 will be able to provide up to 1A to its load, if ever you needed that. Everything is much less stressed. The only other significant change is that the load is now low-side.

In both these last two designs, inputs can be 24V without upsetting anything,  but anything above 0.7V will be considered "high".

Comment: I enjoyed reading your explanations and once again thinking about these switch circuits. I just want to ask why you put an ideal diode in series with a Zener diode in the equivalent circuit of the base-emitter junction? In my opinion, it must be Zener diode only...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist ah, good question, sorry I never explained. The simulator doesn't model reverse breakdown, so I have to insert a zener diode to demonstrate that behaviour. However I only want zener characteristics to take effect during reverse bias, and I don't want to influence the existing junction's behaviour when forward biased. If I placed the zener diode directly in parallel, there would effectively be two diodes in parallel, altering junction behaviour. Therefore, I use the ideal diode to ensure that the zener diode is only "present" during reverse bias.

Comment: Simon, I understand your point - you "modify" the transistor by adding this property (reverse breakdown). Hmmm, clever trick... And I thought you were replacing the base-emitter junction with this network of a Zener diode and an "ideal" diode in series. I did not pay attention to the fact that the labeled nodes actually connect these networks in parallel to the junctions (because I have not used this method of connection between circuit parts in schematics). But indeed, especially in this case, it simplifies the diagram.

Comment: Definitely a clever trick, I realized it now...  Thus drawn in sides, these networks convey the property to the transistor without cluttering the schematics. If you haven't patented it already, I would add it to the CircuitLab "bag of tricks" and use it in the future :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed response! You definitely went above and beyond what I expected and I appreciate it greatly. I will study your response when I have the time and will let you know if I have any questions about it.

Comment: @SimonFitch is there any particular reason why the PNP transistor was chosen, as opposed to using another NPN transistor and it's base connected to the emitter of Q1? In this scenario I would put the load high-side again, but as far as I can see the principles are the same, the current would still be amplified by two transistors hence the current required for the inputs to sink can remain low.

Comment: @CallumRafferty Yes. An NPN for Q2 would invert (remember, RL goes at the collector), I want current through RL when Q1 is *on*. Also this configuration allows Q1 to draw current out of Q2's base only when Q1 is on. Otherwise you'd need a 1kΩ resistor between +24V and Q1 collector & Q2 base, which would be passing 24mA all the time, on *or* off.